# Possible Exceptions due to IntPtr

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, intptr

I am trying to document all major exceptions that can be caused due to use (or misuse) of `IntPtr`. I tried to search for it, but I am not sure about any other than the `OverflowException`. This is for `interface` documentation.

Can someone provide a link or possibly state the main exceptions that can be caused due to the use of `IntPtr`?

Please let me know if this question does not belong here. I was not sure where to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than `OverFlowException` there is an other one `ArgumentNullException` which may be raised against. [IntPtr.ISerializable.GetObjectData Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348251.aspx).

From the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) it seems that the [OverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx) may occur against.

1. [IntPtr Constructor (Int64)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/837ksy6h.aspx)
2. [IntPtr Explicit Conversion (IntPtr to Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a8d37fb.aspx)
3. [IntPtr Explicit Conversion (Int64 to IntPtr)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7kz90hb.aspx)
4. [IntPtr.ToInt32 Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.toint32.aspx)